# How do we calculate the upper sum and lower sum of an Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do we calculate the Upper and Lower Sum of an Integral?

I am trying to calculate it to for :

$$\int_1^2 (3-4x) dx$$

Is there a Formula?

Comment: do you know $F(x)=\int (3-4x) dx$? if yes, then it is $F(2)-F(1)$

Comment: @chenbai so its just integrating?

Comment: There are different (equivalent) definitions of upper and lower sum, depending on your text book / lecture. For better advices, give your definition and state, what you have done so far and where you are stuck. (Riemann) Integration is defined through upper and lower sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upper and lower sums can only be computed explicitly for special examples, like the example in question, or for an exponential function. For the example at hand do the following: Partition the interval $[1,2]$ into $N$ equal parts $I_k:=[x_{k-1},x_k]$ with $$x_k:=1+{k\over N}\qquad(0\leq k\leq N)\ .$$ Looking at the graph of $f$ it is then easy to set up the upper and lower sums with $\sum$ signs. In order to actually compute these sums you need formulas like
$$\sum_{k=1}^N 1= N,\qquad \sum_{k=1}^N k={N(N+1)\over2}\ .$$